# Sending more than the default data to message view on Laravel 5.1 PasswordResets

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm a newbie on Laravel and wanted to know that if there is a way in which you could send more than the default data to the message view (the one that contains the message of the sent email for resetting password)?

The default data that it receives includes just the token and user info. My user table has: id, username, email, password, user_role. But I have another table "seller" that contains the name and last_name fields and of course the foreign key that connects seller with user, so, I want to retrieve the name from the seller table also and send it to the view of the sent message, any ideas?, I've done it modifying the trait that sends the email, but, I've been told that modifying traits is not a good idea. How can I do this without modifying them?, I'm using laravel 5.1, by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a trait called `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords`. It has a bunch of functions that do the job.

You only need to find the function you want to edit and copy that in the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController` and edit the content of the function as you wish.

By doing this you are simply over-riding the default function by your own custom function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On that trait there's a function called postEmail, but I don't see where it gets and sends the whole user, I think that the file that gets the job done is the one on Illuminate\Auth\Passwords, called "PasswordBroker" with the methods "sendResetLink", and "emailResetLink", but that's the class and I would not be able to override the method from the PasswordController, or would I?